# do the same command for each line C#

Tags: c#

I want to do the same code for multiple lines so I created a text file in resources and that's my code

```
string[] commands = File.ReadAllLines(SodaScript.Properties.Resources.ServicesToDisable);
            foreach (string command in commands)
            {
                Process process = new Process();
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                startInfo.FileName = "sc.exe";
                startInfo.Arguments = "config " + command + " start= disabled";
                startInfo.Verb = "runas";
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start();
            }
```

and this is the txt file

[image: the txt file]

but it gives this error

[image: the error]

Comment: Obviously, `SodaScript.Properties.Resources.ServicesToDisable` is not a file name, but a string of text containing a list read from the resource file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use just a regular string array:

```
string[] commands = {
"DiagTrack",
"DusnSvc",
"etc"
};

foreach (string command in commands)
{
    Process process = new Process();
    ...
}
```